# Changing Drupal module template doesn't take effect

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-templates

Okay, this could be a stupid question but I'm kind of new to this Drupal-stuff so I have to ask it anyway :)

I'm trying to implement the FBSS-module (FaceBook Style Status). It all works just fine. I was even able to change some colors and stuff in the CSS-file.

The thing is that I want to do some changes to the template, need to add and remove some stuff. I could hide stuff with CSS, but that sounds like a crappy solution.

I tried to edit:

```
/sites/all/modules/facebook_status/templates/facebook-status-item.tpl.php
```

But it has no effect what so ever. I tried to move it to my theme-folder. Same thing.

And yes, I've cleared the cache.

**Update:** Is there any way to find out if the module is actually using this template-file?

Comment: Anyone? I'm totally stuck here..

Comment: If the module was using the file and you moved it, you would like be getting errors on your screen. I do expect this file does get used but your implementation may not yet have called it. Generally, you cannot move php files out of the directory where they are expected because modules do not know to look elsewhere to find them.

Comment: Then again it would be strange that I don't even get an error when I modify or move it.. =/

Comment: That depends on a couple of things. First, your error reporting may be off in your site. If you've not explicitly turned it off then this is not an issue. Second, the module may be gracefully handling the missing page and perhaps "eating" the error. Lack of an error message doesn't mean one is not occurring. Frustrating I know it is!

Answer (score 3):

first, move it back to the module page - I bet this template is used by module.
secondly, if you change templates, it might require theme registry cache reset, so
go to /admin/build/themes.
You don't have to actually switch themes.

Do you have cache enabled? while developing, it's would be helpful to do 2 things:
1) disable cache
2) go to theme settings, and turn on "rebuild theme registry on every page load" or something that sounds like this.

and to be 100% sure, if you added new template you need to:
1) clear cache
2) go to admin/build/modules (that will rescan template files, etc)
3) go to admin/build/modules (that will rescan info about theme).

in the case of editing existing template, this also can help.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work :( Seems like it doesn't read the tpl-file at all, for some strange reason.

Comment: I totally concur on turning caching off completely during theme development/theme configuration. Basically, any time you make any changes to your theme you want to flush the cache to make sure your changes will be visible. Sometimes they will and sometimes they won't without a flush. In this case, I think you have a different problem but this is good to know. By the way, if you aren't using Drush, that would be the next tool I would like at. Drush lets you clear cache and do a lot of other things from the command line. Sometimes you can crash Drupal and Drush can be only thing that fixes it.

Comment: Hm, I'll take a look at Drush then :) The cache has been off for quite some time now, sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

I've found, and I'm not sure if this solution would suit, that I apply a different theme and then re-apply my adjusted theme and all the changes propagate. No idea why but sometimes I don't see any changes until I do this.

Like I said, this may be isolated to myself, but it's worth a try to help you hit your deadline!